# Regex to remove string and first closing tag

Tags: php, regex, string

I have this code:

```
Blog Title</p><p>Paragraph one.</p><p>Paragraph two.</p><p>Paragraph three.</p>
```

For the life of me, I can't figure out the regex and php functions required to remove `Blog Title</p>` to make my string look like:

```
<p>Paragraph one.</p><p>Paragraph two.</p><p>Paragraph three.</p>
```

I have tried str_replace() but I can't seem to get this to work which makes me think I will need to regex this?

Comment: `^[^<]+</p>` to ''

Comment: substr($str, strpos($str, '>')+1);

Comment: That's giving me an error: $blog_text = preg_replace('^[^<]+</p>', '', $blog_text);  ==  `Message: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier '<'`

Comment: `preg_replace('/^[^<]+</p>/',..`

Comment: `substr($str, strpos($str, '>')+1); ` worked! Can you add as an answer for me to accept? Thank you very much! :)

Comment: `$str = str_replace('Blog Title</p>', '', $str);` [PHP Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/02bb6ad0d02c1654013d093952aae0498c8002ef)

Comment: That wouldn't work as there are different "Blog titles" ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made an example that works, the substring solution in the comments works only if the blog title doesn't contain the `>` character

This solution works for any title (as long as it doesn't contain `</p>` )

```
<?php

$string = 'Blog Title</p><p>Paragraph one.</p><p>Paragraph two.</p><p>Paragraph three.</p>';

echo preg_replace('/^.*?<\/p>/', '', $string);
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7c74b08fd574016eb7baf7f616561781897a343f

Also here is a really useful tool if you ever need to make your own regex lines:
https://regex101.com/r/aD9vM8/1

Comment: Really useful, thanks for the full answer and link to regex101 :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are always removing `Blog Title</p>` or, the first 14 characters of the string try

```
$new_string = substr(14, $origianl_string);
```

See PHP docs on substr - http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php